# Javascript + Chrome : Open a webpage, wait to load, mark a checkbox, click a button

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, command-line, cmd, bookmarklet

As the title says, I want to open a webpage, then wait till it gets loaded. After that I want to click a checkbox, then click a button.
To do this, I have saved a bookmark in chrome with script(s) given in the end and somehow it does not work as expected. It does not wait for page to load. I tired with window.onload as well but to no success. Any help is appreciated.

PS: I also want to automate this via Windows task scheduler therefore a command line method to launch chrome and then open this bookmark will be of great help.

Javascript 1:

```
var login = window.open("URL");
login.onload = function() {
login.document.getElementById('checkbox_id').checked = true;
login.document.getElementById('btn_ID').click();
}
```

Above opens webpage in separate window and perhaps that is why it fails. So I tried::

Javascript 2:

```
location.href = "URL";
function login() {
document.getElementById('checkbox_id').checked = true;
document.getElementById('btn_ID').click();
}
setTimeout(login, 8000);
```

This also does not work as expected. If I click the bookmark twice it does its job but that is not what I expect.